# Salesforce apex class, unable for deploy for this organization

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I created a simple apex class but its not allowing me deploy it from vs code. It is giving me "Not available for deploy for this organization". I thought this was strange bc I am able to deploy lwc's.

I gave my user modify all data settings, but not able to see developer console in salesforce as well? Thinking somethings not configured right?

[image]

Comment: Has it ever worked before? Do you have "author apex" profile permission in this org? What is the org's license (in setup - company information). There are org's that can do UI bits (lwc, visualforce) but no apex

Answer (score 0):

Possibly an API version issue, usually dropping it by 1 (see .xml file) is enough to resolve.

Aside from that, Dev Console can be accessed via the settings cog in top-right (and standard System Admin profile should have access to everything, assign that to your user record if not already assigned).

[Settings cog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDex2.png)

Comment: Changing api version didn't do it.
The cog shows the quick settings like the screen shot above which I was confused about? Doesn't look like the standard salesforce I am used to

Comment: @Keegz are you referring to the Classic view? You can switch to Classic by clicking your avatar and selecting 'Switch to Salesforce Classic' [like so](https://i.imgur.com/FnAuBEN.png).

There are a few other things you can try on [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/344264/not-available-for-deploy-for-this-org-error-using-vscode) (doesn't appear to have resolved for them, but might for you). 

Just to be sure, you're not trying to deploy to a Production org, correct?